# Validation of radio button group using jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

How to perform validation for a radio button group (one radio button should be selected) using jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: Look the answer from c.reeves in http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-plugin-radio-buttons-dependent-fields

Comment: Out there is a new jQuery validator that is very powerfull and easy to use.
You can check it out: http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/

Comment: don't want to include entire a library for something as simple as this

Answer (score 116):

With newer releases of jquery (1.3+ I think), all you have to do is set one of the members of the radio set to be required and jquery will take care of the rest:

```
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="blue" class="required"> Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="red"> Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="green"> Green
```

The above would require at least 1 of the 3 radio options w/ the name of "my options" to be selected before proceeding.

The label suggestion by Mahes, btw, works wonderfully!

Comment: This is now the best answer for me with the updates to jQuery. +1.

Comment: The only problem with this is when none of them are checked, jQuery validate highlights the first radio button in red, but in reality you probably want to highlight ALL of them. Also, once you check any radio button, the red should go away.

Comment: @Haacked You could use the errorPlacement callback function in the validation options to place the error message somewhere meaningful?

Comment: @Haacked: adding `focusInvalid: false` to the `validate()` options will prevent the highlighting of the first radio button.

Comment: I always do it this way and position the error label in the errorPlacement function. This is what I do for radio buttons: if (element.is("input:radio")) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }

Comment: @Haacked probably late now but if you put required to ALL jQuery will highlight all of them and will validate when one is checked

Answer (score 26):

use the following rule for validating radio button group selection

```
myRadioGroupName : {required :true}
```

myRadioGroupName is the value you have given to name attribute

Comment: Note that if you want to control the position of the label, you can provide your own error label where you want it with the text you would like: <label for="myRadioGroupName" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>

Comment: @Tom it's useless to write yourself the `label` tag for the error, actually the plugin adds automatically this error label tag.

Comment: Rather a long time ago, but I imagine what I was trying to do was to place the <label> elsewhere in the DOM, rather than where it was created automatically by the plugin. Also, it's quite possible the plugin behaviour has changed in the last 5 years...

Comment: Sad how it requires the "name" instead of the "type" here for custom errors.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use this:

```
<fieldset>
<input type="radio" name="myoptions[]" value="blue"> Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="myoptions[]" value="red"> Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="myoptions[]" value="green"> Green<br />
<label for="myoptions[]" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
</fieldset>
```

and simply add this rule

```
rules: {
 'myoptions[]':{ required:true }
}
```

Mention how to add rules.

Comment: But this would bring errors on HTML5 validation I believe as the for attribute needs to be an ID reference (which we can't set 3 radio button's to the same ID).

Comment: There is a BIG difference between the name attribute and the id attribute.

Comment: Please not that a radio button should return only one value, therefor, the `name="myoptions[]"` is a bit confusing since it hints multiple values can be returned.

Comment: Puts the error message on top.     

       <style> 

     .radio-group{ 
          position:relative; margin-top:40px; 
     } 

     #myoptions-error{ 
         position:absolute; 
         top: -25px; 
      } 

     </style> 

     <div class="radio-group"> 
     <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="blue" class="required"> Blue<br /> 
     <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="red"> Red<br /> 
     <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="green"> Green </div>
     </div><!-- end radio-group -->

Answer (score 6):

As per Brandon's answer. But if you're using ASP.NET MVC which uses unobtrusive validation, you can add the data-val attribute to the first one. I also like to have labels for each radio button for usability.

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="color" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<p><input type="radio" name="color" id="red" value="R" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please choose one of these options:"/> <label for="red">Red</label></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="color" id="green" value="G"/> <label for="green">Green</label></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="color" id="blue" value="B"/> <label for="blue">Blue</label></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to validate is like this.

```
var $radio = $('input:radio[name="nameRadioButton"]');
$radio.addClass("validate[required]");
```

I hope my example will help you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Wound up just writing a custom highlight and unhighlight function for the validator. Adding this to the validaton options should add the error class to the element and its respective label:

```
        'highlight': function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if($(element).attr('type') == 'radio'){
                $(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").each(function(which){
                    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + this.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
                    $(this).addClass(errorClass);
                });
            } else {
                $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
                $(element).addClass(errorClass);
            }
        },
        'unhighlight': function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            if($(element).attr('type') == 'radio'){
                $(element.form).find("input[type=radio]").each(function(which){
                    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + this.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
                    $(this).removeClass(errorClass);
                });
            }else {
                $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

code for radio button -

```html
<div>
    <span class="radio inline" style="margin-right: 10px;">@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female",false) Female</span>
    <span class="radio inline" style="margin-right: 10px;">@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male",false) Male</span>
    <div class='GenderValidation' style="color:#ee8929;"></div>
</div>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" id="create"/>
```

and jQuery code-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#create').click(function(){
        var gender=$('#Gender').val();

        if ($("#Gender:checked").length == 0) {
            $('.GenderValidation').text("Gender is required.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puts the error message on top.

```css
.radio-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
} 

#myoptions-error {
    position: absolute; 
    top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-group"> 
    <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="blue" class="required"> Blue<br /> 
    <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="red"> Red<br /> 
    <input type="radio" name="myoptions" value="green"> Green
</div><!-- end radio-group -->
```