# How to validate the radio button and checkbox?

Tags: jquery, validation

For radio button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select-number').click(function() {
                if ($('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('Please select something!');
                    return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

It is working fine when no radio button is selected. But When I select the radio button and submit the form Then also it is giving me the alert message `'Please select something!'` Is there any good tutorials available for validation using `Jquery` for `newbie`.

Comment: Can you post the full html at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What type of element is #select-number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attaching to the `click` event of the `submit` button (there are no inputs inside *that* element).  Instead, attach to the `submit` event of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formID').submit(function() {
        if ($('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Please select something!');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This has the advantages of catching all the way the `<form>` may be submitted, as well as looks for `input:radio` buttons in the correct spot.  You can also shorten/simplify it down further:

```
$(function() {
  $('#formID').submit(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input:radio:checked').length == 0) {
      alert('Please select something!');
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @xasjaiod123 - can you show your markup?, it's hard to debug without it.

Comment: it seems he just copy/pasted ur code..so if this was the case and for @xasjaiod123 if you don't have other forms in your page then instead of `$('#formID')` use `#('form')` :-)..anyway, do add your markup if you want to get the most from Nick ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're not seeing if a single radio is checked, rather checking if all are checked

```
if ($(this).find("input:radio:checked").length > 0) {
    return true;
} 
else {
    alert('Please select something!');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This logic is equivalent to the original :)

Comment: trying to come up with some jsfiddle now but I'm not sure what his HTML looks like

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) plugin is quite good and easy to get started with.  If you're new to jQuery, you're probably better off trying out the plugin and focusing on other basics.  You'll figure out some validation as you go, but this can get you validating (client-side) like a pro very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of passing 'this' as second parameter to the $('input:radio') function, because passing this to the call makes jQuery to search within the context of this (which I assume is the Submit button).
Try this...

```
$(document).ready
 (
  function() 
  {         
   $('#select-number').click
   (
    function() 
    {                 
     if ($('input:radio').is(':checked')) 
     {                     
      return true;                 
     } 
     else 
     {                     
      alert('Please select something!');                     
      return false;             
     }         
    }
   );      
  }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help [Validation of radio button group using jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin)