# jquery validate radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

```
$('#webForm').validate({

                            rules : {

                                chos: {
                                    required : true,

                                },

                            },
                            messages : {

                                chos: "Please select radio button" ,

                            },

                        });
                    });

<input type="radio" name="chos" value="phone"/>
<input type="radio" name="chos" value="email"/>
```

The above code is not working.  I need radio buttton validation for the above code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation of radio button group using jQuery validation plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin)

Comment: srry its not working for me ..plz help

Answer (score 2):

The provided code is not valid object notation (although it may be accepted by some browsers). Try:

```
$('#webForm').validate({
    rules : {
        chos: {
            required : true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        chos: "Please select radio button"
    }
});
```