# jQuery checkbox validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

Using this jQuery validation plugin.

http://www.benjaminkeen.com/software/rsv/jquery/index.php

I want to validate a checkbox group with JS, but when i use the statement:

```
rules.push("required,accomodationtype[],Please check all that apply");
```

or

```
rules.push("required,accomodationtype\[\],Please check all that apply");
```

for this kind of checkbox group:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="accomodationtype[]" id="accomodationtype_0" value="hotel1">Hotel1<BR>
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="accomodationtype[]" id="accomodationtype_1" value="hotel2">Hotel2<BR>
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="accomodationtype[]" id="accomodationtype_2" value="hotel3">Hotel3<BR>
<INPUT type="checkbox" name="accomodationtype[]" id="accomodationtype_5" value="other"> Other (please specify)<BR>
<INPUT type="text" name="accomodationtypeother" id="accomodationtypeother">
```

It doesn't validate and it immediately posts the form. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

### Update

I have custom error handler. Tried Alper's suggestion getting this error message:  `errorInfo[i][0].focus is not a function`

```
function errorHandler3(f, errorInfo)
{
    for (var i=0; i<errorInfo.length; i++)
    {
        // errorInfo[i][0] contains the form field node that just failed the validation, e.g.
        errorInfo[i][0].focus();
        // errorInfo[i][1] contains the error string to display for this failed field, e.g.
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: errorInfo[i][1]
        });

    }


    if (errorInfo.length == 0) tcrform_submit();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: try using accomationtype instead of accomationtype[] in the jQuery call?

Comment: it gives error, this field doen't exist

Comment: Ironically, the not-so-comprehensive demo page for the validator you linked does not show how to validate checkboxes or checkbox groups. I would contact the author if you're set on using that validator.

Comment: tried, he did'nt answered. Using this validator, because of very simple usage. You can create custom error handler.

Comment: check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lz5gg/1/ it is working as expected.

Comment: seems it doesn't work with custom error handler.. see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will help, this post is dealing with radiobuttons but perhaps the same rules apply
[Validation of radio button group using jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

there's not enough information for this issue.
Please attach the entire code (js, html), so that we can debug for you.

and for my first glance, I think there must be an "js error" occurred in your code. so I suggest that you should install firebug and make it open focusing "console" tab. then you will see the error message for the senario: "It doesn't validate and it immediately posts the form. "