# How to check two radio buttons with the same groupname

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

i have a group of Radio buttons and i need to check if one has been clicked if not then throw an erorr how can i validate the below with Jquery?

```
<legend>Follow Opening Script?</legend>
<p>
    <strong><asp:RadioButton GroupName="OpeningScript" CssClass="inline-radio" ID="rdoOpeningScriptYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" TextAlign="Right" /></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <strong><asp:RadioButton GroupName="OpeningScript" CssClass="inline-radio" ID="rdoOpeningScriptNo" runat="server" Text="No" TextAlign="Right" /></strong>
</p>
```

Comment: You should really post the actual HTML, not the asp tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin will this help?

Answer (score 0):

Here a jsfiddle example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/xYLxX/

Answer (score 0):

Register event on document ready:

```
$('input[name="OpeningScript"]').click(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Change the index to get the status of particular item:

```
$("input[name*=OpeningScript]")[0].checked
```

To get the text try:

```
$("input[name*=OpeningScript]:checked + label").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/sHXMy/)**</kbd>

Add a `button` to your HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="check" value="check" />
```

And write a function for its `click` to check:

```
$(function () {
    $('#check').on('click', function () {
        if (! $('[name="OpeningScript"]:checked').length) {
            alert('Please choose an option');
        }
    });
});
```