# How to get jQuery Tools validation working on a group of radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-tools

Just can't figure it out... (and judging from a long bout of web searches, I'm not the only one.)  I have jQT validation working properly otherwise; just not for radios -- all I want to do is confirm that at least one of the buttons has been clicked.  I've been experimenting with setting up a custom validation function via $.tools.validator.fn, but I can't find the right thing to use for the selector.  I didn't have much luck looking at the source code; any advice out there?  Thanks!

Comment: This question seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that this is a hack, and needs to be adapted to your needs. Here's what I came up with and there may be better options out there.

Sample markup:

```
<form action="" id="theForm">
    <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male" class="requiredCheckbox" /> <label for="male">Male</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female" /> <label for="female">Female</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="unknown" id="unknown" /> <label for="unknown">Unknown</label>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="button" id="validate" value="Validate" />
</form>
​
```

Javascript with custom validation method and a little hackery:

```
$.validator.addMethod('requiredCheckbox', function (val, elt) {
    var valid = false;

    $('input[name=' + $(elt).attr('name') + ']:radio').each(function(inx, elt) {
        if (elt.checked === true) {
            valid = true;
            return;
        }
    });

    return valid;
}, 'Select at least one checkbox');

var options = {
    errorPlacement: function(error, elt) {
        $(elt).before(error);
    },
    errorElement: 'div'
};
var validator = $('#theForm').validate(options );

$('#validate').click(function() {
    $('#theForm').valid();
});​
```

Here's JSFiddle with a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9DRcz/

Fun problem to work out though :-)

Comment: A good start! There's a catch in that I was looking for a way to get the validator in jQuery Tools (not raw jQuery) to work, since I'm using that elsewhere in my code.  But I've gotta have radio button validation, so I may have to suck it up and switch to the code that works.  I'll likely be back with more on this...

Answer (score 2):

Where I am (or ended up):

- I gave up on trying to get the validation stuff in jQuery Tools to work with radio buttons.
- @MK_Dev got me on the path to using the jQuery Validation plugin (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), for which much thanks.  However, the additional method in his answer wasn't needed -- I'm getting radio button validation by loading the validation plugin, giving one of the radio buttons a class of "required", and calling .validate() on the form.  Works fine.
- @jason's reference to [Validation of radio button group using jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin) also paid off.  My last bit of confusion about all this is that there's some discussion on that page about how the bassistance validation plugin isn't needed -- that jQuery (1.3.2??) can do validation all by itself.  Could be, but I couldn't figure it out.

In any case, I now have some working validation, which is more than I could say earlier today.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. They don't give any radio button examples in the jQueryTools Validator documentation though: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html

Here is the relevant source code.

In the page head, include:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").validator();
});
</script>`
```

In the page body:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="next-page.php">
  <label>Option One</label>
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="RadioGroup1" id="RadioButton_1" />
  <label>Option Two</label>
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="RadioGroup1" id="RadioButton_2" />
    <label>Option Three</label>
  <input type="radio" required="required" name="RadioGroup1" id="RadioButton_3" />

  <input type="submit" name="continue_to_next_page" id="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Let us know if it works for you.