# How to check if the radio box with dynamic names is checked

Tags: jquery, html, validation, radio-button

I have a multiple rows of radio boxes like this

```
<input id="m_0" type="radio" value="m" name="c_0">
<input id="f_0" type="radio" value="f" name="c_0">

<input id="m_1" type="radio" value="m" name="c_1">
<input id="f_1" type="radio" value="f" name="c_1">

<input id="m_2" type="radio" value="m" name="c_2">
<input id="f_2" type="radio" value="f" name="c_2">
```

So, I want to validate if the radio has been selected in each row

I tried this way - `if ($('input:radio[name="c_"+i]:checked').val()) {`

where i = 0,1,2... but it didn't work

any idea how can I change it to work? thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277589/validation-of-radio-button-group-using-jquery-validation-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val` returns a string which is always `true`,  you should use **[`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** property instead:

```
if ($('input:radio[name=c_'+i+']:checked').length) {
```

Note that you are concatenating the variable's value incorrectly.

Comment: this didn't work, for the first row, i selected m_0, but still it is going to else

Comment: What is `i` in your code? Can you provide a demo on jsfidde.net?

Comment: your first answer actually worked with slight modification :
if ($('input:radio[name=c_'+i+']:checked').length) {

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the code:

```
$("input[type=radio]").prop("checked") )
$("input[type=radio]").is(":checked") )
```